# Create a prototype method that works alone but can also have sub-methods

Tags: javascript, prototype

I don't know how else to name the title, sorry.

Here is an example, I want to be able to do this:

```
var str = 'bla bla bla';

str.do(a).thenDo(b) 

//but i also want to be able to do this:
str.do(a) // which will do something different

// I have tried this but it doesn't work:
String.prototype.do = function(a) {
  //here is some code to get the 'str' variable, then:
  var self = {};
  self.thenDo = function(b) {
    var someCalculations;
    return someCalculations + a + b;
  }
  self = function() {
    //this is supposed to be the do(a) function
    var moreCalculations;
    return moreCalculations + a;
  }
  return self;
}
```

NOTE: thenDo() needs to use the 'a' parameter from do() so something like this will *not* help in what i'm trying to achieve:

```
String.prototype.do = function(a) {
   var moreCalculations;
   return moreCalculations + a;
}
String.prototype.do.thenDo = function(b) {
   var someCalculations;
   return someCalculations + a + b;
}
//it doesnt work, thenDo() cant get the 'a' parameter
```

Furthermore I need this for a library that I'm developing so any jQuery answers will not help.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like extension methods, which are not currently supported but have a few pending proposals (the `::` operator is one).

Comment: Your `thenDo()` needs to be a property of the objects *returned* from `.do()`, not the function itself. That's what libraries like jQuery do: return objects of some consistent type to enable the "chaining" style.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my bad, I changed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said:

> ```
> str.do(a).thenDo(b) 
>
> //but i also want to be able to do this:
> str.do(a) // which will do something different
> ```

It's **impossible** for the `do(a)` part of that to do something *different* depending on whether its return value is used. E.g., the `do(a)` part of `str.do(a)` and `str.do(a).thenDo(b)` cannot know it's meant to do something different in those two cases. It just doesn't have that information (which is a Good Thing™).

You could make this work:

```
str.do(a)();           // Does one thing
str.do(a).thenDo(b);   // Does something else
```

Note the `()` at the end of the first one. That's the trigger that lets us differentiate the two cases:

```js
(function() {
  function String$do(v1) {
    // This function is called if the caller uses () on the result
    function immediate() {
      console.log("something: ", v1);
    }
    // This is called if they use .thenDo() instead
    immediate.thenDo = function(v2) {
      console.log("something else: ", 1, v2);
    };
    return immediate;
  }
  Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "do", {
    value: String$do
  });
})();

var str = "testing 1 2 3";
str.do(42)();
str.do(42).thenDo(67);
```

---

Side note: When extending built-in prototypes (which many advocate against), **always** be sure to use `Object.defineProperty` or `Object.defineProperties` and use the default for the `enumerable` flag (or explicitly set it to `false`) so you don't create an enumerable property. That won't help with naming conflicts, but it may help with code naively assuming only the default set of built-in prototype properties in `for-in` loops, `in` checks, etc.

Comment: Thanks this works. Is there a way to remove the last two brackets from `str.do(42)();` so it can be typed as `str.do(42);` ?